# Convergence in $L^1$ along a directed set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have a question of notation in this theorem:

[image]

This is lemma 1 in [this paper of Cassese](https://doc.rero.ch/record/12754/files/cassese_SPL_2007.pdf). I don't know what the notation $P(f_uH)$ stands for. Also, I really appreciate any further explaination for this lemma.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like De Finetti's notation with $P(f_uH) = \int_H f_u dP$. Note that he does say just before the lemma that sets are identified with their indicators.